# SQL total amount where deposits are added and withdrawls subtracted

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 -------------------------------------------  
|  CustomerID |    Action      |    Amount  |
|-------------------------------------------|
|   111       |     deposit    |      100   |
|   111       |    withdrawl   |       25   | 
|   222       |     deposit    |      500   |
|   222       |     deposit    |      100   |
|   333       |    withdrawl   |      100   |
|   333       |     deposit    |      100   |
 -------------------------------------------
```

Write a query that for each `customerID` would display the total `Amount` for that customer, where Deposit Actions are added to the total and Withdrawls are substracted from total

Comment: This screams "Homework", at least have the decency to acknowledge it.

Comment: this was not for homework. This was for personal learning

Comment: @fdellagr, "homework" *is* for personal learning...

Answer (score 3):

Using a CASE WHEN, you can treat the `AMOUNT` column differently in calculation based on the value of another field(`ACTION`).

```
SELECT CUSTOMERID,
SUM(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'DEPOSIT' THEN AMOUNT
         WHEN ACTION = 'WITHDRAWL' THEN -AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM
TABLE1
GROUP BY CUSTOMERID;
```

Comment: what if I want to keep a running balance. So if I see want to add Action into my select statement and group by statement? any idea

Comment: `SUM(CASE ... END) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY some_other_column)` - In SQL data sets are intrinsically ***un-ordered*** so you ***must*** have another field to order it all by.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `IF - ELSE logic` ( if `withdrawl` or `other` "there's only one alternative") to write a simple query by using `DECODE` pseudo-code :

```
select CustomerID "Customer ID", sum(decode(Action,'withdrawl',-Amount,Amount)) "Total Amount"
  from inventory
 group by CustomerID 
 order by CustomerID;
```

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40a57/1)

Comment: This answer adds everything together and does not subtract Withdrawls

Comment: @fdellagr no, you can see from Demo that it subtracts withdrawls

Comment: @fdellagr - This part ensures that `'withdrawl'` is negative, and everything else is positive: `decode(Action,'withdrawl',-Amount,Amount)`

Comment: @MatBailie what if I want to keep a running balance. So if I see want to add Action into my select statement and group by statement? any idea